# Is it worth making a separate DATE table or not?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

If I have a table like this:

```
my_table
=======================
id    date    some_data
```

Does it make any sense to pull the `date` out to it's own table? The `date` field would use the `date` data type. So it would now look like this:

```
my_table
==========================
id    date_id    some_data

dates
==========
id    date
```

According to MySQL, `date` data type = 3 bytes. The `date_id` would need to be a max of `MEDIUMINT` (3 bytes) in order to get the same result. A normal `INT` or `BIGINT` exceeds the storage requirements of a `DATE` type.

A downside to a separate table is that the queries would be more complicated because I am joining another table.

Are there any other ramifications that need to be taken into account as to whether or not to split the `date` field into it's own table? My gut reaction is that it's not worth doing unless you are dealing with a small set of dates (small enough to use `TINYINT` or `SMALLINT`).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Save space? Is the table expected to have millions of rows?

Comment: A separate date table is a feature of star schema data warehouse designs. In that setting, however, they tend to have additional columns like DayOfWeek, Month, Quarter, FinancialYear and such. These help produce aggregates at the cost of more storage.

In an OLTP setting I have never seen this done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to me that is a classic example of over-thinking your design.

Keep the dates in the same table so they can be easily indexed with other columns if necessary, and not take up 3 times as many bytes, and not make life a living hell for future developers.

Comment: Agreed, the only reason I see to do this if you somehow were sharing this fact with many source ids, just going one step too far in "normalizing".

Answer (score 2):

Normalization is often a good idea, either for flexibility or space.  But Normalizing "continuous" values, such as `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `FLOAT`, etc, is generally a mistake.  Don't do it.

Perhaps the biggest problem occurs when you decide to filter on a date range, and you find the `JOIN` is killing performance.

Even if you had fewer than 255 dates (I'm thinking of `TINYINT UNSIGNED`), `DATE` is not worth turning into an id.

While we are talking about ids, generally they should be `UNSIGNED` and `NOT NULL`.  And almost never is `BIGINT` warranted.